# Shortkey for Code-Assist in xcode

Tags: xcode, code-assist

Is there any way to help me using the code-completion in xcode beside seleceting to 'to-be-inserted' item and than using ?

Example:
When searching for `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` I am writing `CGCo` and get a very long list (all starting with `CGContext`), the selected item is somewhere far away from `CGContextS`.
Is there a key to autofill until the next camelcase (here `Context`)? Than the next input could be `set` for getting a very smaller liste with `CGContextSet`-Items?

There is something simular in eclipse. Typing `NPE` in the 'Open Type'-Dialog shows a list with all classes containing 'NPE-camelcases' like NullPointerException.

I hope, this question is understandable.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a key to autofill until the next camelcase (here Context)?

Yes, presss the `<Tab>` key.

Comment: New question: I'm looking for `tableView:height....`, but <TAB> just helps until `tableView`, every next key clears the list. Is there an other key for that?